# Flyway supportsChangingCurrentSchema() exception

Tags: flyway

I am using `FlyWay` with `SpringBoot`. It connects to a local `Oracle` database, which runs in a Docker container. The application works well and the flyway migrations also work well with Maven.

I try to execute the migrations automatically when the application starts. I do not need to create a schema as it already exists.

Hence, I set this in `application.properties`:

```
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.schemas=...
spring.flyway.url=...
spring.flyway.user=...
spring.flyway.password=...
```

My expectation is that flyway will run all migrations. Instead, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Database.supportsChangingCurrentSchema()Z
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) [spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at eu.europa.ec.agri.afs.summabackend.Application.main(Application.java:14) [classes/:na]

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.Database.supportsChangingCurrentSchema()Z
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.base.BaseDatabaseType.createDatabase(BaseDatabaseType.java:143) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:174) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar:na]
at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:124) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.10.jar:2.7.10]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.26.jar:5.3.26]
... 18 common frames omitted
```

I couldn't find anything on internet about this.
Does anybody know what is going on?